# In pandas, how to perform value counts of gender(or any categorical variable) based on another categorical column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
gender   doctor name
female       A
 male        B
 male        A
female       C
female       B
```

How to do value counts of gender based on doctor's name?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need `groupby` with aggregate [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['doctor name','gender']).size()
print (df)
doctor name  gender
A            female    1
             male      1
B            female    1
             male      1
C            female    1
dtype: int64
```

It is same output as [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html), only values in each group are sorted:

```
df = df.groupby(['doctor name']).gender.value_counts()
print (df)
doctor name  gender
A            female    1
             male      1
B            female    1
             male      1
C            female    1
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
#[1000000 rows x 2 columns]
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L1 = ['e', 'f','g','h', 'i', 'j']
L2 = ['female','male']
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':np.random.choice(L1, N), 
                   'doctor name': np.random.choice(L2, N)})

#print (df)


In [43]: %timeit (df.groupby(['doctor name','gender']).size())
10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit (df.groupby(['doctor name']).gender.value_counts())
1 loop, best of 3: 254 ms per loop
```

```
#output is sorted by index
print (df.groupby(['doctor name','gender']).size())
doctor name  gender
female       e         82944
             f         83422
             g         83706
             h         83200
             i         83004
             j         83521
male         e         83405
             f         83503
             g         82891
             h         83666
             i         83525
             j         83213
dtype: int64

#output is same, only sorted
print (df.groupby(['doctor name']).gender.value_counts())
doctor name  gender
female       g         83706
             j         83521
             f         83422
             h         83200
             i         83004
             e         82944
male         h         83666
             i         83525
             f         83503
             e         83405
             j         83213
             g         82891
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

If need `crosstab` fastest solution is add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['doctor name','gender']).size().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
print (df1)
doctor name  A  B  C
gender              
female       1  1  1
male         1  1  0

df2 = df.groupby(['doctor name','gender']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df2)
gender       female  male
doctor name              
A                 1     1
B                 1     1
C                 1     0
```

**Timings2**:

```
#used same df as in timings

In [64]: %timeit (df.groupby(['doctor name','gender']).size().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0))
10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit (pd.crosstab(df.gender, df['doctor name']))
1 loop, best of 3: 215 ms per loop

In [66]: %timeit (pd.pivot_table(df, index='gender', columns='doctor name', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0))
1 loop, best of 3: 251 ms per loop
```

Comment: I have a column called `sex` with `female` or `male` values in the same column therefore how can I access the total females and total males separately by that `sex` column? Thanks. I've tried using `value_counts` and `size()` but no go.

Comment: @TokyoToo - Do you think `df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()` after this solution?

Answer (score 4):

Apart from `groupby`, if you're looking for a crosstab dataframe view. There are two direct ways to do it.

Using `pd.crosstab`

```
In [52]: pd.crosstab(df.gender, df.doctor)
Out[52]:
doctor  A  B  C
gender
female  1  1  1
male    1  1  0
```

Using `pd.pivot_table`

```
In [53]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='gender', columns='doctor', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
Out[53]:
doctor  A  B  C
gender
female  1  1  1
male    1  1  0
```